# What should my Dyson Sphere be called

Tags: dyson-spheres, names

I have written out a Dyson Sphere world with four cities that surround four colossal oceans (each >16000000x the volume of jupiter). I've worked on the flora, fauna, government, pseudo-gravity and so many other things, but I don't have a name for the Sphere itself.

It's year of completion is around 3450. It's construction began after the destruction of the earth due to being knocked out of orbit during WW4 ~2350 which lasted a few weeks (WW3 was relatively uneventful). Most of human history was lost, though several Exabytes of data were preserved containing 3D scans of artifacts and some information concerning language and culture. This data led to the oceans being named and shaped after the Greek letters Theta ϴ, Omicron O, Phi φ and Omega Ω. The cities are named after the ocean they surround.

What should the sphere as a whole structure be called? Ancient references are good but astral reference is also cool. Parts of the world refer to history, the stars, mythology. For example, two transportation systems are named after the 4200 pole stars, Cephean (north) and Chameon (south).

Comment: I think I have to vote to close this as opinion-based, unless you have some criteria for rating names objectively.

Comment: Well, @Cadence , if the name is appropriate and can be related to the sphere, it will be considered a good name. Like John Locke's 'Kugel' idea of translating sphere into German.

Comment: @Cadence Oh please don't, this will be fun and at least there's a reasonable number of criteria to narrow it down.

Comment: I think you'll find [this website](https://www.fantasynamegenerators.com) useful. Choose any generator for any genre and just generate to your heart's content. Combine names if you want to, or just smash your keyboard for surprising results.

Comment: From the inside, the sun is always in the sky and (artificial?) gravity pulls you to the sphere, so it would feel like you're in the *bottom* of the universe.  That clicks with the ancient Greek geocentric cosmology where earth was the "bottom" that all the crap from heaven fell onto.  Is there a Greek word for that idea?  That's what I'd go with.  On the other hand, if you stood on the other side of the sphere, you might feel like you were on top of the greatest mountain ever seen.  What's the Greek word for "top"?

Comment: @Joe Greek doesn't use Arabic letters, so one translation of bottom is "πυθμένας"

Answer (score 3):

How about Kugel?

That is sphere translated into German, and apparently Earth was also a German word. I also tried translating metal, but metall sounded pretty much the same. If you want to translate the entire word, you will get Dysonsphäre, which I think is still not as good as sphere.

**Edit:**

Kugel sounds a lot like Kalgash, which you can use if you want to throw a reference to the planet in Isaac Asimov's sci-fi novel [Nightfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_novelette_and_novel)).

Comment: Nice idea, translating it into another language. That opens a lot of possibilities!

Comment: @ZoneWolf I edited my answer to also reference the planet Kalgash.

Answer (score 2):

"Spherey Mc. Sphere-Face"

Just kidding. Maybe **"Anemoi" after the four winds in Greek Mythology**, since you have four cities and four oceans, and your folks already seem to be fond of what Greek history is available to them.

Comment: R.I.P Boaty Mc. Boat-face, you made us proud. Anemoi sounds good, with the Greek connection and the four of everything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chronus is a pretty good one I think.

I like Skoll the most though, the wolf that eats the Sun in certain versions of Norse Mythology.

Comment: Why not have both? Chronus is usually depicted as utterly mountainous. Skoll devours the sun upon ragnarok. Chronuskoll? Chronus-Skoll?

Comment: @ZoneWolf It's your sphere, you decide. X'D